# How to run a TestNG class from another class

Tags: selenium, testng

Hi When i run the following testNG file as a standalone script if executes as expected.

```
public class TESTTNGClass {
    WebDriver driver;
  @Test
  public void f() {
      System.out.println("In Test");
  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {

      System.out.println("Before Test");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      System.out.println("After Test");
  }

}
```

O/P:

```
Before Test
In Test
After Test
```

But why does the same not work when called from another class. Please help to achieve the same when triggered from another class. Following is the class calling the test class

```
public class TESTClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TESTTNGClass t = new TESTTNGClass();
        t.f();
    }

}
```

O/P:

```
In Test
```

Comment: What are your usecase to run a class from another class ? Have you executed like this without testNG ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

In the process of understanding and experiment with `Java` & `TestNG` you have diminished the `Annotation` power of **TestNG**.

- When you are executing `TESTTNGClass.java` as a `TestNG Test` all works well. No issues.
- When you are executing `TESTClass.java` as a `Java Application`, Java only understands `main()` where you are creating an object of `Class` **TESTTNGClass** and then you are calling the **method** `f()`. As Java Compiler have have no idea of `BeforeMethod`, `Test` & `AfterMethod` **Annotations** of `TestNG`, it simply executes `f()` method, prints **`In Test`** and ends execution.

About how to do it:

- Replace `main()` by some other name `foo()`.
- Bring `f()` from "TESTTNGClass" class into "TESTClass" class.
- While you write "TESTClass" class extend "TESTTNGClass" class.
- Execute "TESTClass.java" as a `TestNG Test`

Your Application will look like:

- **TESTTNGClass** Class:

  ```
  package Q44240531_TestNG_Main;

  import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

  public class TESTTNGClass 
  {


    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {

        System.out.println("Before Test");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
    System.out.println("After Test");
    }
  }
  ```
- **TESTClass** Class:

  ```
  package Q44240531_TestNG_Main;

  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class TESTClass extends TESTTNGClass {

            @Test
            public void f() 
            {
                System.out.println("In Test");
            }
  }
  ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: it definitely answers one of my question, but how can I achieve the same output when called from another class? should i call these 3 methods separately ?

Comment: @Programmer Great !!! Replace `main()` by some other name `foo()`. Bring `f()` from "TESTTNGClass" class into "TESTClass" class. While you write "TESTClass" class extend "TESTTNGClass" class. Execute  "TESTClass" class. Can you Accept the Answer if it Answers your Question? Thanks

Comment: that scenario would be valid if there was only one "TESTTNGClass" what if there were few other classes like "TESTTNGClass1", "TESTTNGClass2" and so on..?

Comment: @Programmer I have updated my Answer as per your Question. Please Accept the Answer if it caters to your Question. Feel free to raise a new Question as per your new requirement. Thanks

Comment: I had understood the scenario, but this might not work if there are multiple testNG classes and one class should drive all the other test classes

Comment: I figured out how to do it using factory annotation... this answer almost answered what i wanted ... thank u

Answer (score 0):

public class TESTClass extends TESTTNGClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TESTTNGClass t = new TESTTNGClass();
    try{
      t.f();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is already *the* correct answer for this problem. Your answer is competely redundant, besides it's low quality.